# Header bar is invisible

Tags: react-native, view

I'm very new to React Native and I'm trying something out right now. I also got the first demo app running smoothly.
Now I would like to test the example from the tutorial and add a header bar with window title and a button in the upper right corner. For that I just extended MyNewProject. However, if I start the app now, no bar will appear at the top, only the text in the middle of the window will be displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the program code:

```
const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'My new project',
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => Alert.alert('This is a button!')}
        title='Info'
      />
    ),
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try change this

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'My new project',
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => Alert.alert('This is a button!')}
        title='Info'
      />
    ),
  };
```

to this:

```
static navigationOptions = props => {  return {
    title: 'My new project',
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => Alert.alert('This is a button!')}
        title='Info'
      />
    ),   
   } 
 };
```

Comment: Ok, I just changed and tested. Unfortunately, it does not work either. Could it perhaps have something to do with the styles or the Android version (Android
5 in my case)?

Comment: One more information: I just tested the app on Android 8.0. Again, no header bar will be displayed. So it can not be the OS version.